# Error when running executables from mapped network drives

Tags: windows, permissions, firewall, network-shares

We have an active directory environment with some shares on a file server running windows server 2008 r2, the clients run windows 7 and map the file shares to drives on their machine, this is accomplished via a script on each users profile.

Some users have some portable versions of applications like truecrypt when the executable is located on a mapped drive the system gives the error: "The system cannot find the path specified", other applications try to access a sql server database and those say that the server cannot be found, others that try to open a tcp port say they cannot do so, you get the idea.

If those applications are copied to a local drive, they work without issues which makes me think the system for some reason does not trust code running from the network drives.

to make the story complete the issue started happening when we had to fail over the file server as the original was broken (everything worked from the original one) so we are now on our backup server, I have checked the permissions for users on the shares and they all match what we had on the original, i am thinking that i am missing a setting somewhere there it currently says "Trust shares from server A" and it should say "Trust shares from server B"

Comment: This doesn't sound like a permissions issue. It sounds like a connectivity issue. When the problem occurs, can you ping the server using the same name being used to establish the connection? Also, review the System and Application event logs on the clients and server for events logged around the time the issue occurs.

Comment: Do they work if you access the files using a UNC path?  Does Process Monitor - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon - show anything of interest when you carry out the tasks mentioned?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the quick responses, regarding the system and application logs, they display the same errors that are displayed to the user. ping works correctly, and resolves to the correct address, executing from a UNC `(\\server\share\folder\executable)` path yields the same issues